# Java.net Connection Reset using Rserve

Tags: java, r, sockets, exception, rserve

I am getting an exception while trying to run a R program via Java. The connection is being established but then the error is being thrown while the evaluation of the R code starts.

```
Rconnection connection = new RConnection();

System.out.println(String.valueOf(connection.isConnected())); //Output: True
connection.eval("source('C:\\Users\\Vini\\Documents\\test.R')"); //Exception in this line
```

I have already started the `Rserve` in `R`.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
  at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.protocol.RTalk.request(RTalk.java:213)
  at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.protocol.RTalk.request(RTalk.java:180)
  at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.protocol.RTalk.request(RTalk.java:250)
  at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:231)
  at integration.Integration.main(Integration.java:36)
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed
  at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:234)
  at integration.Integration.main(Integration.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`isConnected`](http://rforge.net/org/doc/org/rosuda/REngine/Rserve/RConnection.html#isConnected()) does not guarantee that after connection was established it will report correct state:

> Note that currently this state is not checked on-the-spot, that is if connection went down by an outside event this is not reflected by the flag

You need to check `Rserve` log to check that request was processed successfully

Comment: i cannot execute the code above because it is taking too long to establish a connection